# Is it possible to add a custom class field for content types in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

What I have done until now, is to create a custom type content in Drupal from: Structure > Content Types > Add content type.

I managed to add some fields to my content type, such as title, body and language.

What I want next, is to add a text input field where I can specify a name for a class that will encapsulate the content.

I want to avoid adding html into the page body field, because this will be changed and I might lose the `"<div class="myClassName">` tag.

Is this possible somehow?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using field formatter module: https://drupal.org/project/field_formatter_class

I hope it's useful.

Regards.

Comment: I just installed this module, along with Field_formatter_setting api that is required for this, but it gives me a huge error when I try to enable it: " PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: INSERT INTO {batch} (bid, timestamp, token, batch) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1,..."